# R: How to overload + operator to call a method which adds a function to an R6 class?

Tags: r, methods, operator-overloading, r6

My aim is to overload the `+` operator in order to call a method on an [R6 object](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/gg-add.html). Here is a toy example with an R6 object of class `aclass` that has a method `add_function(foo)` to store some arbitrary function in itself.

I want to substitute the call to `add_function(foo)` by `+ foo` in the style of [ggplot2's +.gg or +(e1,e2)](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/gg-add.html). I checked the [ggplot2 github code](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/tree/master/R) but could not figure this out.

### Here is an R6 object to which we can add arbitrary functions

```
library(R6)
# The class (called aclass) looks like so:
Aclass <- R6Class("aclass",
  public = list(
    fun = NULL,
    x = NULL,
    initialize = function(x) {
      self$x <- x
      return(invisible(self))
    },
    # this is the function adding part
    add_fun = function(fun) {
      self$fun <- substitute(fun)
    },
    # and here we execute the functions
    do_fun = function() {
      return(eval(self$fun)(self$x))
}))

# Say, we want to add this function to an aclass object
foo <- function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)
```

### This works

```
# Instantiate class
my_class <- Aclass$new(c(0,1,NA))
# Add the function
my_class$add_fun(function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))
# my_class$add_fun(foo) # this also works
# Execute the function - beautiful - returns 0.5
my_class$do_fun()
```

### This fails

My goal is to do the same as above, i.e. adding foo to the object, but now by overloading the + operator to do the job in a nicer way

```
# Let's try to overload the + operator
`+.aclass` <- function(e1, e2) {
  return(e1$add_fun(e2))
}

# option 1
my_class <- Aclass$new(c(0,1,NA)) + foo
# fails
# Looking at my class we get
my_class
# > my_class                                       
# e2

# option 2 <--- this is my end goal
my_class <- Aclass$new(c(0,1,NA)) + mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)
# also fails because then R tries to execute the function
# > Error in mean(x, na.rm = TRUE) : Object 'x' not found

# Note: in this case, the custom +.aclass is not even called,
# but R calls the normal + method I think
```

I am not sure how to solve this or if it is actually possible...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by removing the `substitute` in your `add_fun` function and returning `self` (because you are affecting it to a new object)

```
    # this is the function adding part
    add_fun = function(fun) {
      self$fun <- fun
      self
    },
```

it will work with

- `my_class <- Aclass$new(c(0,1,NA)) + foo`
  and also with
- `my_class <- Aclass$new(c(0,1,NA)) + function(x) mean(x,na.rm=TRUE)`

for your goal case it would be harder

- `+ mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)`

even ggplot2 functions are evaluated (eg `labs(x="title")` will evaluates to an object of class **label** that being added to an ggplot will finally call function `ggplot_add.labels`)

By slightly tweaking your goal case using formula notation it can be solved

- `+ ~mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)`

using this code

```
`+.aclass` <- function(e1, e2) {
  se2 <- substitute(e2)

  # detect formula
  if(is.call(se2) && as.character(se2)=="~") {
    # build template function
    e3 <- substitute(function(x) y)
    # replace y in template by formula body
    e3[[3]] <- se2[[2]]
    # use our templated formula function
    e2 <- e3
  }
  e1$add_fun(e2)
  e1
}
```

Finally using higher level functions available in rlang we can simplify it to

```
`+.aclass` <- function(e1, e2) {
  e1$add_fun(rlang::as_function(e2))
  e1
}
```

Note that the formula like function will need to have **.x** instead of **x**